# Extracting specific words from the list of attributes and return all the possible words to a new field with the help of defined dictionaries

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-parser

I need to extract specific words from the list of attributes and return all the possible words to a new field with the help of defined dictionaries. (using Python Parser in ArcGIS)

Example

1. `Apples are red in colour`
2. `Grapes are green in colour`
3. `Grepes are sour in taste`
4. `Mangoes are sweet to taste`
5. `Mnagoes are yellow in colour`

Defined dictionaries:

Mangoes:('Mangoes','Mnagoes')
Grapes: ('Grapes','Grepes')

Expected Output:

1. `Apples,red`
2. `Grapes,green`
3. `Grapes,sour`
4. `Mangoes,sweet`
5. `Mangoes,yellow`

[image]

This is the code i tried with:

```
def replace(work_name): 
    if any(x in work_name.lower() for x in ['dam','dem','daem']): 
        return 'Dam' 
    elif any(x in work_name.lower() for x in ['pond','pound','talab']): 
        return 'Farm Pond' 
    elif any(x in work_name.lower() for x in ['plantation']): return 'Plantation' 
    else: return 0
```

Comment: def replace(work_name):
  if any(x in work_name.lower() for x in ['dam','dem','daem']):
    return 'Dam'
  elif any(x in work_name.lower() for x in ['pond','pound','talab']):
    return 'Farm Pond'
  elif any(x in work_name.lower() for x in ['plantation']):
    return 'Plantation'
  else:
    return 0

Comment: Please check the added image

Comment: Field Calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand the fruit example. But looking at your code, the output, and the expected output, I think your problem is that you are returning as soon as you find a keyword. In that way you are always going to get just one keyword. Try something like this,

```
def replace(work_name):
    keys = []
    if any(x in work_name.lower() for x in ['dam','dem','daem']): 
        keys.append('Dam') 
    if any(x in work_name.lower() for x in ['pond','pound','talab']): 
        keys.append('Farm Pond')
    elif any(x in work_name.lower() for x in ['plantation']):
        keys.append('Plantation')
    if len(keys) == 0:
        return 0
    return ','.join(keys)
```

One thing to note is, the order of the keys do not correspond to the appering order of the words that match the key. I am not sure if you need this as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working.

Comment: Great, glad it helps!. Please mark the answer as correct.